# Screen run command, detach and get output

Tags: bash, usb, gnu-screen, tty

I am trying write a script which connects and runs command on /dev/ttyUSB0 after that gets the output.

```
screen -d -m 'SCREEN COMMAND' -L /dev/ttyUSB0
```

But this does not create an output file. How can I solve this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: @mtndesign In the future, please check the code formatting, you also have to remove the \`backticks\`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pyserial` library of python. I think you can solve it with this library. You can find a tutorial in [here](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

`screen` is good to have your terminal session to run detached. However, it was not designed to automatically run commands on terminals.

For this purpose, another tool was developed - [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

`expect` allows to script human-like interaction with programs running on terminal.

It is powerful tool, but it is also another scripting language to learn and can be a bit tedious. If you are familiar with Perl, [Perl Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.21/Expect.pod) module can save you a lot of effort (there are also expect modules for other scripting languages like Python).

One more note. In your case, it seems that `/dev/ttyUSB0` is serial-over-USB device that may connect or disconnect at any time. If you want to automatically maintain interaction to this serial-over-USB interface, you may consider either watching for this device to appear/disappear and reconnect automatically (say in Perl script), or add udev rule (under `/etc/udev/rules.d`) which will automatically start your handler program as new USB device is connected.